# tcpdump dhcp ipv6 capture filter

Tags: ipv6, tcpdump, dhcp

I want capture DHCP IPV6 packet from a specific client

I know how to do in IPV4

IPV4 DHCP packets including a specific Client MAC Address

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -vvv -s 0 '((port 67 or port 68) and (udp[38:4] = 0x3093bcbaddb1))’ -w /tmp/dhcp-ipv4.pcap
```

Which is the tcpdump capture filter with a specific "link layer address"?

IPV6 DHCP packets including a specific Client MAC Address

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -vvv -s 0 '( (port 546 or port 547) and (???????) )’ -w /tmp/dhcp-ipv6.pcap
```

Comment: IPv4 broadcasts a DHCP request, but IPv6 does not have broadcast. IPv6 DHCP uses a special multicast address used by IPv6 DHCP servers, and your host will reject any multicast packets (usually at the hardware) unless you have an application that has subscribed to the multicast group. Also, MLS-snooping switches will not even send such a packet to your host unless your host has sent an MLS request.

Answer (score 0):

To select a mac address, I would use something like:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -vvv '(port 67 or port 68) and ether host 01:23:45:67:89:AB'
```

I expect that syntax "ether host xxxx" would also work for IPv6

Search for ether host in your tcpdump manual or check this page: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/t_commands/tcpdump.html